# how to make a random int value in c for coin flipping

Tags: c, random

How do I make a random integer value in C?
I need it to act like a coin flipping.
Here is what I've tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        if ((int)(((float) rand() / ((float) SHRT_MAX)) * 2) > 0)
            puts("etz");
        else
            puts("pali");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Too intricate for my taste. You could just do `if (rand() % 2)`

Comment: The marked duplicate is not really a duplicate - that question is about _biasing_ the coin, not a fair coin.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Poor idea -- see the posted answer.

Comment: Don't use [Tab] on Stack Overflow. It won't format your post correctly. Use 4-space indentation instead.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your solution is `rand()` always returns a positive integer so the expression `(int)(((float) rand() / ((float) SHRT_MAX)) * 2) > 0` is always true except on platforms where `short` and `int` are the same width.

Another problem is that `rand()` returns a value from zero to `RAND_MAX` not `SHRT_MAX` - it is unlikely in a modern library that `RAND_MAX == SHRT_MAX`

Your solution may be adapted thus:

```
(float)rand() / RAND_MAX > 0.5f
```

but the casting and floating point comparison is unnecessary and over complex, it can be tested thus:

```
rand() > RAND_MAX / 2
```

It is likely to be suggested that you could just test for odd/even with:

```
rand() % 2 == 0
```

but that is problematic in some poorly implemented algorithms because it relies on the randomness of a single LSB - it is likely to work in a modern library, but best avoided to ensure code portability.